# Filtering data in laravel and handling the views

Tags: php, laravel

I have a tv show netflix-esque project I'm building where I have a `Shows` page which I want to filter on format. Each show contains episodes which can have a tv, dvd and bd format.

Currently I'm filtering using separate routes and controllers which extend the base `ShowsController`.

```
Route::get('shows/view/{type}', ['as' => 'shows.viewtype', 'uses' => 'ShowsController@viewType',]);
Route::get('shows/bluray',['as' => 'shows.bluray','uses' => 'ShowsBlurayController@index']);
Route::get('shows/dvd',['as' => 'shows.dvd','uses' => 'ShowsDVDController@index']);
Route::get('shows/tv',['as' => 'shows.tv','uses' => 'ShowsTVController@index']);
```

Example of one of the format controllers

```
class ShowsBlurayController extends ShowsController
{
    public function index()
    {
        // Set user state for browsing bluray
        Session::push('user.showtype', 'bluray');

        $shows = $this->show->getBlurayPaginated(16);

        return $this->getIndexView(compact('shows'));
    }
}
```

I use the `getIndexView()` method (in the `ShowsController`) to determine one of 2 available views: `poster` and `list`.

```
public function getIndexView($shows)
{
    $viewType = get_session_or_cookie('show_viewtype', 'list');
    if ($viewType == 'posters') {
        return View::make('shows.index', $shows)
            ->nest('showsView', 'shows.partials.posters', $shows);
    } else {
        return View::make('shows.index', $shows)
            ->nest('showsView', 'shows.partials.list', $shows);
    }
}
```

The shows are filtered based on the episodes:

```
public function getBlurayPaginated($perPage)
{
    return $this->getByFormat('BD')->with('tagged')->paginate($perPage);
}
private function getByFormat($format)
{
    return $this->show->whereHas('episodes', function ($q) use ($format) {
        $q->whereHas('format', function ($q) use ($format) {
            $q->where('format', '=', $format);
        });
    });
}
```

The problem is that I want to do this in a clean way. When a user selects a format, that filter will be applied. Currently all of this is kind of scattered across controllers and doesn't quite make sense.

I also thought of doing something like this in the `routes.php`:

```
Route::get('shows/format/{format}',['as' => 'shows.format','uses' => 'ShowsController@index']);
```

And then handle the filtering in the index, but that also seems a weird place to do that.

This approach does work, but I don't want to screw myself later on with it. I'm planning a simple search which should take the filter into account.

In other words, how can I organize the code in such a way that getting data from the database will take the filter into account which has been set? (Session states maybe?)

Comment: Can you clarify a bit more ? Did it show any error ?

Comment: @MD.AtiqurRahman no no erros. It works fine, it's just not scalable and not DRY

Comment: look at answer bellow , hope that solve your problem .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Route::get('shows/format/{format}',[
    'as' => 'shows.format',
    'uses' => 'ShowsController@index'
]);
```

I think you're on the right track here.  I would go so far as to produce a [factory](http://www.phptherightway.com/pages/Design-Patterns.html) and inject it into the controller.  The purpose of this factory is to construct a formatter that will supply your view with the correct data:

```
// ShowController
public function __construct(ShowFormatFactory $factory, ShowRepository $shows)
{
    $this->factory = $factory;
    // NB: using a repository here just for illustrative purposes.
    $this->shows = $shows;
}

public function index($format = null) 
{
    $formatter = $this->factory->make($format);

    return View::make('shows.index', [
        'formatter' => $formatter,
        'shows' => $this->shows->all(),
    ]);
}

// ShowFormatFactory
class ShowFormatFactory
{
    public function make($format)
    {
        switch($format) {
            case 'blueray':
                return new BluerayFormat(); break;

            case 'dvd': /* Fallthrough for default option */
            default:
                return new BluerayFormat(); break;
        }
    }
}

// ShowFormatInterface
interface ShowFormatInterface
{
    public function format(Show $show);
}

// BluerayFormat
class BluerayFormat implements ShowFormatInterface
{
    public function format(Show $show)
    {
        return $show->blueray_format;
    }
}
```

Then in your view, since you are guaranteed to have an object that will provide you the format requested for a given show, just call it:

```
@foreach($shows as $show)
<div class="show">
    Chosen Format: {{ $formatter->format($show) }}
</div>
@endforeach
```

This solution is testable and extensible will allow you to add other formats later on.  If you do, you would need to add a discrete `case` statement in the factory for each different format, as well as write a rather slim ~5-7 line class to support the new format.

Comment: Perhaps there is some miscommunication, but why would you filter through the shows in the view? Wouldn't it be better to apply the filter in the repo? That's how I'm doing it now. I pass the filtered shows to the view. The problem is that I'm delegating the filter action in a weird way. The formats are also stored in the DB and have a `Format` model attached to them. Updated my question too.

Comment: This is an index view, so there are no filterings, it's going to display every show.  What is different between the paths `shows/format/dvd` and `shows/format/blueray` is the object created in the factory is different. Since you will need to run through every show at least once in the view, it makes the most sense to call it there rather than take an O(n) and turn it into a O(2n) solution if you instead call the formatter from the repository.